# MySQL "less than" operator doesn't bring correct results

Tags: php, mysql

I am using paginating in PHP and MySQL to view next/previous records. The query as below:

```
$domain_id = 1;
$user_id = 8;
$limit = 5;
$sql = 
'SELECT users.user, users.id FROM users 
  JOIN users_matched_domain ON
        users.id = users_matched_domain.user_id  AND 
        users_matched_domain.domain_id = '.$domain_id.' AND 
        users.id < "'.$user_id.'" 
  ORDER BY users.id ASC LIMIT '.$limit;
```

Table users as below:

```
id       user
==       ===
1         a
2         b
3         c
4         d   
5         e
6         f
7         g
8         h
9         i
10        j
11        k
.         .
.         .
```

The above query doesn't work well, it brings user IDs starting from the first ID in user_id table. i.e. rows ids (1 to 5), it should give (3,4,5,6,7) as they are less than the user id 8. While, when I update the above query as below:

```
users.id > "'.$user_id.'"
```

Then the paginating working fine for (next, next, next), I get 1-5, then 6-10, 11-15, etc.

I would greatly appreciate your hints. Thanks for your help.

Comment: After LIMIT there must be 2 numbers - starting and count of records. You have only 1

Comment: You're getting the first 5 results where the user id is less than 8, ordered by ascending user id. So the records you're getting are the ones with the lowest user ids, which is why you're getting 1-5, instead of 3-7.

Comment: @LHristov . . . That is simply not true.  `LIMIT` can take one parameter.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Always glad to learn something new :) Never used Limit with only 1 arg

Comment: Thanks my friends for your inputs. I think the best thing is to use the DESC and then sort the result array in ASC order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `desc` sort to the the five just before what you are looking at:

```
 . . .
 ORDER BY users.id DESC . . .
```

In other words, you want the sort to be `desc` for `<` and `asc` for `>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I actually tried the the DESC but I got the IDs in reverse order, so I though I can do something from the MySQL. But seems no solution other than the DESC, so I will do that and then I will sort the elements in ASC. Thanks once again and please accept my kind regards.